# How to link google play purchase with the corresponding subscription base plan and offer using Google Play Developer API?

Tags: android, google-api, in-app-purchase

There are two endpoints in Google Play Developer API providing information about the subscription purchased by the user (depending on the purchase token) - [purchases.subscriptions](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions) and [purchases.subscriptionsv2](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptionsv2). What is the proper way (and does it even exist?) to link that information with the corresponding subscription from Google Play Console, including the concrete base plan and offer?

v1 request doesn't contain any subscription identifiers, v2 request contains `lineItems[].productId`, which refers to the whole subscription. But none contain any information about base plans or offers, which were used to make the current purchase.

The second and smaller part of the question is where are located purchase price currency and amount in the v2 endpoint, which were available in the v1 endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Google has fixed this problem in the last API update and now [there are](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptionsv2#OfferDetails) `basePlanId` and `offerId` fields in `OfferDetails` in purchases.subscriptionsv2 request.